# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SupportedEllipticCurvesExtension

Tags: java, ssl, http2

I tried both the latest alpn-boot jars from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty.alpn/alpn-boot
but it makes no difference, they don't even contain that class.

I'm using the Sun JDK.

Where do I find the correct jar?

Comment: That class is part of JSSE and in JRE/lib/jsse.jar in every Oracle JDK 7 and 8 install I have (and presumably the corresponding JREs also but I don't install those separately) which is available to the normal system classloader -- but I don' t know about boot. And it's in the same place in my (fewer) CentOS packages of OpenJDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this truly just doesn't work with the Oracle Sun JDK. It works with OpenJDK

Comment: Have you check the exact version numbers? I'd assume that the real reason is that your Oracle Sun JVM has a different version from your OpenJDK JVM.

Answer (score 6):

I'm the maintainer of the `alpn-boot` jar.

I'm assuming you are using JDK 8.

For each JDK 8 release you must check the corresponding [table](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions) to see what is the exact version of the `alpn-boot` jar that you must use.

Whether you are using OpenJDK or Oracle's JDK, it does not matter: so far we have not been reported of any difference between the two with respect to the classes modified by the `alpn-boot` jar.

As of this writing, JDK 8u121 is in the process of being released, so you have to wait a bit for us to finish the work.